# rails 4.2 link_to method: No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, link-to

I'm simply trying to construct a `link_to` with `method: :delete` to call the `destroy` method in my users controller:

```
<%= link_to 'disable token', user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Which generates HTML that looks like:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/6">disable token</a>
```

My `application.js` file has:

```
//= require jquery                                                                                                                                            
//= require jquery_ujs
```

And, in fact, i know the javascript is loaded and doing what it is supposed to, because it generates the 'Are you sure?` alert dialog.

However, when following the link I get the following:

```
No route matches [POST] "/users/9"
```

And indeed there is no such route, because my only routes are:

```
users_path  GET /users(.:format)    users#index
user_path   DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
```

The mystery (to me) is WHY is Rails doing a POST to this route in the first place?  You'll note that the URL is correct ("/users/9") but that the HTTP verb is not: POST.

The parameters of the request are getting set:

```
{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"VcAVJF1/f9mwjNI4GPteRtDiyjKobnioF0hIQvF+3BVMzUnIoHymM2Z3w2sqSLJqJ11sZ/tIHt78aA9
}
```

Here you can see the `_method` key being set to `delete` as it should be, so why the routing error?!?

I'm stumped.

**Edit:** If i change my `link_to` call to include `remote: true` Rails routes it to the proper route!  So, as a "fix" for this i've changed my controller to use UJS, but i don't like this because, well, as far as I can tell what i had before should work!

Here is the `link_to` call which sends a proper DELETE request as JS:

```
<%= link_to 'disable token', u, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, remote: true %>
```

Comment: BTW -- i've trolled through the various Q&A on the Stack related to link_to and method: :delete, but could not find anyone with this exact problem.  If there is an extent answer, please post it!  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it would help to use something like chrome developer tools and inspect the HTML generated by this `link_to`. You can also use this to make sure you're looking at the right link.

Comment: which rails version is used in your application?

Comment: Hi, what is `u` in this line: `<%= link_to 'disable token', u, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>`?

Comment: I've answered the above comments by editing the body and title of my question.  But more direct answers in order: see body for HTML that link_to generates; I am using Rails 4.2.5.2; u is an instance of a User model.

Answer (score 0):

Just try explicitly stating the controller action and method also (note `@user.id` is an example, you may be referencing it differently) with [`url_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for):

```
<%= link_to 'disable token', url_for(action: :destroy, id: @user.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Adrian, but i'm afraid it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, was the same error returned? Also, can you add the contents of you routes file to your question? Then, if I can help further, I will modify my answer or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion in this case is that there is some other javascript that is overriding the rails behavior.

I had the same issue (but with it getting a GET request, rather than POST). It turned out to a completely unrelated bit of JS that was too general in the selector, and was calling jquery's `stopPropagation` on all anchor tags surrounding a button, which was how my particular HTML was set up.